# How can I connect to the SFTP server with sudo via WinSCP?

Tags: ssh, sudo, root

I want to use WinSCP to connect to the Raspberry Pi standard SFTP server. I also need to have root access. How can I do this without logging in as root (using sudo)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy. By default the stfp-server of a Raspberry Pi is located at: */usr/lib/sftp-server*, so we need to get WinSCP to execute it with sudo.

- Go to your WinSCP profile (*Session > Sites > Site Manager*)
- Click on *Edit > Advanced... > Environment > SFTP*
- Insert `sudo su -c /usr/lib/sftp-server` at "SFTP Server"
- Save and connect

Comment: For more details see WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

Comment: Strangely, you can still encounter permission errors if you try to duplicate a file. I had to download the file, rename it locally, then reupload.